# Target of URI doesn't exist: 'package:flame/collisions.dart'

Tags: flame

[This](https://github.com/flame-engine/flame/blob/main/examples/lib/stories/collision_detection/circles_example.dart) example for collision detection has an import that is not found, do you know why?

It says: `Target of URI doesn't exist: 'package:flame/collisions.dart'`

```
pubspec.yaml
 flame: 1.0.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new collision detection system was not released in `1.0.0`, you can depend on `1.1.0-releasecandidate.4` to use it (we'll release `1.1.0` on Friday).

Comment: Thanks, will there be many changes -I am just starting on flame and wondering if I should wait or is releasecandidate.4 incl. new stuff?

Comment: There are some breaking changes between `1.0.0` and `1.1.0`, but it will not be many changes now during the week from rc4 to `1.1.0`, just bug fixes if any bugs are reported. In 30 minutes or so we'll release rc 5, which has small bug fixes in it. So if you are planning to do the migration at some point anyways I'd recommend diving into the RC right away. If you need help you can also join our discord: https://discord.com/invite/pxrBmy4